# DeepMinds Kinetics-400 dataset label time mismatch

Tags: dataset

i found mismatching labels from kinetics dataset

this sample is labeled longer then source

[image]

```
"0RDYvF3uIhg": {
        "annotations": {
            "label": "stretching arm",
            "segment": [
                118.0,
                128.0
            ]
        },
        "duration": 10.0,
        "subset": "test",
        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0RDYvF3uIhg"
    }
```

total length of video is 2:06 == 126 seconds
but label says from 118 to 128 seconds

```
"0H77yH7IQGQ": {
    "annotations": {
        "label": "passing American football (in game)",
        "segment": [
            2.0,
            12.0
        ]
    },
    "duration": 10.0,
    "subset": "test",
    "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0H77yH7IQGQ"
}
```

this sample is labeled 2 to 12 seconds
but original video length is 9 seconds

is this label wrong?
or they have used another unit of time?